# How to emulate Windows window snapping/grid shortcuts?

Tags: windows, shortcut-keys, compiz

In Windows, you have these shortcuts:

- <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Arrow Up ↑</kbd>: Maximize current window
- <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Arrow Down ↓</kbd>: Unmaximize
- <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Arrow Right →</kbd>: Maximize, set width as half the screen width, stick window to the right
- <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Arrow Left ←</kbd>: Maximize, set width as half the screen width, stick window to the left

I’m particularly interested in the last two shortcuts.

Comment: Now I know how to do it in windows 7! :D yay!

Comment: Can anyone update these answers for Ubuntu / Lubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I use the "grid" option of CompizConfig Settings Manager.  "Grid" is developed as an extra plugin, so you have to install [compiz-fusion-plugins-extra](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz-fusion-plugins-extra) [image: Install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra] package (I couldn't see this in "software center", so did it through synaptic).

Once you have the plugins installed, in CCSM, go to "Window Managment", then select "Grid".  I modify my "put left" to be <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd> (and do likewise for "put right", "put top", and "put bottom").  I map <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to be "put center".

I am not sure about W7, but the GREAT thing about GRID is that if you hit it once, it will go to half the screen.  A second time goes to 1/3 of the screen.  A third time has it take up 2/3 of the screen.  Then, a fourth has it back to half.  So, you can set up documents side by side that need 1/3 or 2/3 of the screen as well as equally sharing 1/2 of the screen.

A MUST plugin for me in Linux!  And it works great!

Unity will be coming with a "snap feature" included, but I like the keyboard to do this setup for me!  CCSM GRID it is!

Comment: Nice! Not seen that before. I prefer the default numpad shortcuts though.

Comment: I am on a laptop so that is why the need to change out the default numpad shortcuts.  Forgot to mention that in the original reply.

Comment: Grid works great and on the laptop you can use the common "fn" key to use keypad: try it ;)

Comment: True about the "fn" key, but I just happen to feel that I can't do this as easily "without looking", so I have found that I need to change to something that can be done quick and sight free.  Hitting ctrl + shift is a one finger operation, and the arrows are easy to find "by feel".  I know the same is true for many who have gotten used to using the FN keypad, but not me... nice it is such an easy tweak for everyone to have their preference.

Comment: Great! Actually the combination with the numkey and the amount of options available is amazing! Thanks :)

Comment: @iveand some screenshots of where to set this up in ccsm would make this answer nearly perfect!

Comment: Just a warning: the Compiz Config Settings Manager has issues that can screw up your session.  I ran into this, I think.  Consider whether you have the technical knowledge to back out of installing the package (and rolling back your settings) before you commit to it.

Comment: Does this work on Gnome?

Answer (score 17):

For Ubuntu 11.04 (natty) and 11.10 (oneiric) you can do it if you have a keypad/number pad on your keyboard. Nothing else needs to be installed:

> Ctrl + alt + NumPad 4 (entire left side)
>
> Ctrl + alt + NumPad 5 (maximize)
>
> Ctrl + alt + NumPad 6 (entire right side)
>
> Ctrl + Alt + NumPad 9 (top right corner)

Full list: In the "Window Placement" of [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

Comment: I'm on 12.04 LTS and Ctrl-Alt-NumPad5 works for me there also.  I can't get other numbers to work, but I'm willing to blame the fact that I'm running Ubuntu in Virtualbox on OSX with a third-party keyboard.

Comment: Are these settings configurable? I cannot seem to find them under `System Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts`.

Answer (score 14):

It worked for my Ubuntu 14.04. Just do the same thing you did in windows, but this time add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, so it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+Arrow.

Comment: The only thing it doesn't do that I'm used to it doing on Windows is moving it across monitors.  If it's on monitor 2, no matter how many times you hit ctrl + super + left, it will stay on monitor 2.