# How do I view split on top/bottom/corners

Tags: 18.04, 22.04, shortcut-keys

I want to create a shortcut to pack the view of the current program on an area of my window.

It's like `super+left` shortcut, that shows as "split view on left" on keyborad->shortcut[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmEHc.png) configuration, but I want to set `super+numpad_8` to "split view on top", `super+numpad_9` to "split view on top right corner", and so on.

How can I manage to define such shortcut? Which command can I define on "Command" in the "Add Custom Shortcut" window[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmEHc.png)?

[image: Add Custom Shortcut Window]

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: See here https://askubuntu.com/questions/26346/how-to-use-window-snapping-for-ubuntu and here https://askubuntu.com/questions/25409/how-to-emulate-windows-window-snapping-grid-shortcuts

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: The links pointed to by @codlord are outdated and don't work for Gnome. They are more than 10 years old and are designed for older Unity desktop. I am having a hard time to do this in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 5):

Following **GNOME extensions** might help you:

1. [Tiling Assistant - GNOME Shell Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3733/tiling-assistant/)
   Adds a Windows-like snap assist to the GNOME desktop. It expands GNOME's 2 column tiling layout and adds many more features.
   For more details see [Tiling-Assistant Wiki](https://github.com/Leleat/Tiling-Assistant/wiki) and [article on itsfoss "How to Use Tiling Assistant on GNOME Desktop".](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tiling-assistant/)
2. [Put Windows - GNOME Shell Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/)
   Fully customizable replacement for the old compiz put plugin.

- Move windows to left/right side, bottom/top, center or corner
- Move window to other screen
- Select focused window using the keyboard
- Application based window placement
  Check out this [AskUbuntu-answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089033/30631) for more details including how to install a GNOME extension.

Otherwise [these system features shortcuts and modifiers](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-states.html.en) can help you arrange windows quickly without any extension:

- Move a window by dragging the titlebar, or hold down <kbd>Super</kbd> and drag anywhere in the window. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while moving to snap the window to the edges of the screen and other windows.
- Resize a window by dragging the edges or corner of the window. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while resizing to snap the window to the edges of the screen and other windows.

**Before Ubuntu 22.04:**
[ShellTile - Extensions GNOME Shell](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/)
A tiling window extension for GNOME Shell. Just move a window to the edges of the screen to create a tiling, otherwise move a window over another one, holding down the Control key. Grouped windows minimize, resize, raise and change workspace together. Move or maximize a window to remove it from the group.
[Default keyboard accelerators](https://github.com/emasab/shelltile) that can be joined for quarter tiling:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd> Left : Tile to the left border
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd> Right : Tile to the right border
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd> Up : Tile to the top border
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd> Down : Tile to the bottom border

Comment: Just a heads-up: at the time I'm writing (January 2024) ShellTile is not compatible with Ubuntu 22.04, so I am not able to install it.

Comment: I'm actually using a combination of both Tiling Assistant and Put Windows. Tiling Assistant does most of that I need, but Put Windows has the ability to resize a window to the center of the screen, whereas Tiling Assistant is only able to move windows to the center without resizing them.