# How to can we split a large monitor screen into 2/4 partitions like windows in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, multiple-monitors

I am not able to find a simple solution or a easy method to split a monitor into 2/4 virtual monitors. Saw some very old posts here 10yrs and 5 yrs old where Fake xcinemar and randr were suggested, but no one confirmed if they worked and if they will work on ubuntu 20.04. I am a novice pls help.

Answer (score 1):

What flavour of Ubuntu are you using?

Ubuntu has supported half-page window tiling for a while now, drag window to one side of the monitor or another or use hotkeys. See here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-tiled.html

As far as I know it only supports a split into 2 tiles though.

For more tiles I don't know what it currently supported but perhaps take a look here:
[How to use Window snapping for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26346/how-to-use-window-snapping-for-ubuntu)