# Having two windows next to each other on gnome, similar to the win-left/right shortcut on Win7?

Tags: 10.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to emulate winkey+arrow Windows 7's maximise shortcut keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25409/how-to-emulate-winkeyarrow-windows-7s-maximise-shortcut-keys)

I would like to have two windows next to each other. For those of you who used Windows 7 you probably know that there is a shortcut (win-left/right) to move one window to the left or right half of the screen. I'm looking for a similar feature in Gnome.