# Is window snap/grid part of Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I know Natty comes with the Snap feature like Windows 7 does, but is that part of Unity or Natty itself? Basically, if I switch to Gnome 2 instead of Unity will I still have window Snap?

(If anyone would like to recommend a compiz setting to mimic it, go right ahead)

Answer (score 4):

It is basically a compiz feature, so as long as you dont switch to the "no effects" session (with Metacity as WM) you should be fine.

This has information on configuring it:

- [How to emulate Windows window snapping/grid shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25409/how-to-emulate-winkeyarrow-windows-7s-maximise-shortcut-keys)