# What happened to ctrl+alt+numpad in Ubuntu 12?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore the Ctrl + Alt + Num Pad 4 and 6 window positioning commands?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116744/restore-the-ctrl-alt-num-pad-4-and-6-window-positioning-commands)

I got used to using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad</kbd> to move windows around in Ubuntu 11.04. Since I updated to Ubuntu 12.04, however, numpad shortcuts 4, 6, and 0 don't work. Those are the most important ones!

Is there another set of shortcut keys for these operations, or is there a way to bring them back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I came up with, in case anyone else needs it.

I installed compiz-fusion-plugins-extra over ccsm, which gave me access to window management shortcut keys. From there, I was able to enable the maximize option.

Standard warning with ccsm: use it sparingly. It'll turn on you for, like, no reason.

[Related link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25409/how-to-emulate-winkeyarrow-windows-7s-maximise-shortcut-keys)